# Binding DatePicker to string property of class Model in C# Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, datepicker, type-conversion

I am trying to set `DatePicker` default date to some current date and bind `DateSelected` to string property of my object. I get error like this:

> Unable to cast object of type 'Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ElementNode' to type 'Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.ValueNode'

I store dates in SQLite as strings. Here is the Model class part:

```
    public string Arrivo { get; set; }
    public string Partenza { get; set; }
```

This is the xaml part of the view:

```
    <DatePicker x:Name="pickArrivalDate" DateSelected="{Binding Arrivo}"/>
    <DatePicker x:Name="pickDepartureDate" DateSelected="{Binding Partenza}"/>
```

This is the ViewModel:

```
    public string Arrivo
    {
        get => _tavolo.Arrivo;
        set
        {
            _tavolo.Arrivo = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Arrivo");
        }
    }

    public string Partenza
    {
        get => _tavolo.Partenza;
        set
        {
            _tavolo.Partenza = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Partenza");
        }
    }
```

I guess I should do the conversion but not sure how to achieve this.
Any ideas?

Comment: DateSelected is an event, not a property.

Comment: Oh, so I shouldn't use this to bind  then right?

Comment: You have to set Date property because DataSelected is an event.

Comment: I see. DateSelected is for methods rights?

Comment: don't use string - C# has a perfectly good DateTime class you can use

Comment: ok. I will stich to DateTime.Date then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set `Date` property because `DateSelected` is an event:

```
<DatePicker x:Name="pickArrivalDate" Date="{Binding Arrivo}"/>
<DatePicker x:Name="pickDepartureDate" Date="{Binding Partenza}"/>
```

Note: Properties Arrivo and Partenza, have to be DateTime, so if they are string, you have to use a `ValueConverter`.

Comment: will it need conversion from Date to string anyway?

Comment: Sure, use a ValueConverter: https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters

Comment: @positiveperspective anyway i think that you should use Arrivo e Partenza as DateTime and not string. It would be better. If you found it usefull, upvote. Grazie